# MonoAndroid : "Found a conflict between..."

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

I am evaluating Mono for Android and after build in Mono Develop I get 8 warnings like this:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: Warning: Found a conflict between : 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' and 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Using 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' reference. (Android)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: Warning: Found a conflict between : 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' and 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Using 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' reference. (Android)

and 6 more for System.Core, mscorlib, Mono.data.sqlite etc.

What does that mean and how to get rid off it? (application runs with no problem so far but it's just annoying)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your application is referencing an assembly that is compiled for .NET 4.0 instead of for MonoDroid/MonoTouch/Silverlight (2.0.5).  You are getting lucky that it's working, but there's a decent chance it will break once you try building a release package using linking.

Comment: It's ServiceStack.Text referenced from MonoDroid app - when I deleted reference it compiles without warnings. Strange thing is that the same ServiceStack.text.dll is referenced from MonoTouch application which compiles withour warning - why?